# How to define class attribute after creating class

Tags: c++, class, scope

I am trying to figure out how to define a Variable which is a member of a class in C++, Outside of the normal class body. It may be inside of a Function, or outside of the class. Is this possible. What I need is that the variable should be a member of the class such that if I call Nodesecond.birthdate, it returns the birthdate.
I am attempting to understand the language, there is no real-world application involved.

This was my attempt at doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Nodesecond {
public:
    int Age;
    string Name;
    //  I dont want to define Birthdate here. It should be somewhere else. 

    Nodesecond() {
        this->Age = 5;
        this->Name = "baby";
        this->birthdate = "01.01.2020";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    Nodesecond mynode;
    cout << mynode.Age << endl << mynode.Name << mynode.Birthdate;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Everything that the class has, needs to be specified in the `member-specification` of the class.

Comment: Maybe you'd like a `std::map<>`?

Comment: Unlike Python, you can't add attributes of an object dynamically. Get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::any> attrs;` could achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something close to JavaScript objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

struct Nodesecond {
public:
    int Age;
    string Name;
    unordered_map<string, string> Fields;
    string& operator[](const string& name) {return Fields[name];}
    Nodesecond() {
        this->Age = 5;
        this->Name = "baby";
        *(this)["Birthdate"] = "01.01.2020";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    Nodesecond mynode;
    cout << mynode.Age << endl << mynode.Name << mynode["Birthdate"];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> How to define class attribute after creating class

You can't. Everything that the class has, needs to be specified/**declared** in the [member-specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) of the class.

---

Note the emphasis on **declared** in the previous statement. We must declare everything first inside the class and then we can optionally define that afterwards outside the class.

Comment: But you can later on, outside of the class define extra functions using the [className]::[funcName] (parameters) {code}, if you wrote the function interface inside of the class. 
That is not possible in with variables right?

Comment: @Flavio That is why I wrote **"declared"** and not "defined". Everything needs to be "declared" first inside the class and then you can optionally "define" that afterwards outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, since the class has to be complete by compiletime. However, under some circumstances a std::map<Key,Value> might do the job.